# Do people still play the original Counter Strike online on steam?

Tags: steam, counter-strike

I used to play this game (last time in 2003), but I would like to know if it's still active. So, do people still play this game online? And if so, where is the best place to do this?

Comment: @YUNOWORK - He probably means CS 1.6, which I think is still played by many people.

Answer (score 3):

[SteamCharts](http://steamcharts.com/app/10#1m) shows that Counter-Strike is still played quite a bit. Concurrent playercount is usually somewhere between 5 000 and 20 000 players (worldwide).

This is less than tenth of [Counter Strike: Global Offensive](http://steamcharts.com/app/730#1m), but double C[ounter Strike: Source](http://steamcharts.com/app/240#1m).

Comment: If you're in Europe, you can get a game easily still, just not a competitive one